# Can maximality of a subgroup in a group be preserved under commutator operation?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and  $M$ be a  normal maximal subgroup of $G$.

Is commutator subgroup of $M$ a normal maximal subgroup of  commutator subgroup of G?

it is known that $M^{'}$ is proper subgroup of $G^{'}$.

please find a counterexample or prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the dihedral group $G$ of order $2^{n+1}$, with $n \ge 3$, and $M$ the maximal cyclic subgroup. Then $G'$ is cyclic of order $2^{n-1} \ge 2^{2}$, whereas $M' = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:

$$G=S_5\;,\;\;M=A_5\;,\;\;G'=A_5=M$$ and $M'=A_5$

Comment: you are rigth,but This is actually part of another problem and it is known that commutator of M is proper subgroup of commutator of G and I forgot to write it.Sorry for that.

Comment: @DonAntonio - did you mean $G=S_5$ and $M=A_5$?

Comment: Of course, @NickyHekster. Thanks. Any group of roder less than $\;60\;$ is soluble so it can't be equal to its commutator subgroup. Edited.